# I am really confused regarding few things in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am really confused regarding few things in `UIViewController`, I have already read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and searched lot on the Internet but still confused.

When I want to jump or switch from `firstVC` to `secondVC` how many types of methods are available? I am listing which I know:

1. `UINavigationController`
2. `UITabBarController`
3. `presentModalViewController:`
4. Add secondVC to root view

   - If secondVC is added to root view then how firstVC object will be released?
   - Is it a good practice to add every view I want to jump/switch to root view?
5. `transitionFromView:`

   - I dont understand this portion from Apple doc:

> This method modifies the views in their view hierarchy only. It does
>   not modify your application’s view controllers in any way. For
>   example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a
>   view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view
>   controller appropriately to handle the change.

If I do this:

```
secondViewController *sVc = [[secondViewController alloc]init];

[transitionFromView:self.view toView:sVc.view...
```

Still `viewDidLoad:`, `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:` are working fine: I don't need to call them. So why did Apple say this:

> it is your responsibility to update the view controller appropriately to handle the change.

Are there any other methods available?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the standard methods used are :

1) Using NavigationController

```
 //push the another VC to the stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherVC animated:YES];

//remove it from the stack
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

//or presenting another VC from current navigationController     
[self.navigationController presentViewController:anotherVC animated:YES completion:nil];

//dismiss it
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

2) Presenting the VC

```
//presenting another VC from current VC     
[self presentViewController:anotherVC animated:YES completion:nil

//dismiss it
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Never use the method you described in points 4. It's not a good practice to change root view controller's dynamically. window's root VC is usually defined on applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions after that it shouldn't be changed , if you are to follow apple standards.

**Example for transitionFromView:toView**

```
-(IBAction) anAction:(id) sender {
// assume view1 and view2 are some subviews of self.view
// view1 will be replaced with view2 in the view hierarchy
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 
                    toView:view2 
                  duration:0.5 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    /* do something on animation completion */
                  }];
  }

}
```